# An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' while trying to read a text file using fread

Tags: c++

I'm trying to read a simple text file (here out.wsp) using ***fread()*** but I get " *An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException'* ". I get this error in VS2010 express but when I compile and run it in Linux it's fine. Any idea what's wrong with the code? Also since I'm new in C/C++, is there any other way to do something like this?

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

 int main(){


    char*  wspfile    = "out.wsp";
    FILE*  fp = NULL;

    fp = fopen( wspfile , "r");
    if(fp == NULL) {
        printf("Error: can not open file %s\n", wspfile);
        return -1;
    }   
    rc = fread(wspfile,sizeof(wspfile)-1,1, fp);
    wspfile[rc] = '\0';
    fclose(fp);

return 0;

}
```

Thanks,

Fanttazio

Comment: The standard `fread` does not throw exceptions. Is this really standard C++? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fread/

Comment: This looks like C code (apart from the `using namespace std;` which is pointless).

Comment: @Kirirl This isn't C++. This is C with `using namespace std;`. Character literals are constant in C++, so you get an access violation trying to write to it. fread doesn't throw the exception here - it's an access violation exception thrown by the VC++ runtime.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I'm still learning and you guys help a lot. (Fanttazio)

Answer (score 2):

It is illegal (undefined behaviour) to modify a string literal:

```
char*  wspfile    = "out.wsp";
...
rc = fread(wspfile,sizeof(wspfile)-1,1, fp); /* sizeof() is a sizeof(char*),
                                                not an array which is probably
                                                what you intended. */
```

and this will be the cause of the access violation.

To resolve you *could* change to:

```
char wspfile[] = "out.wsp";
```

or, better, use a different `char[]` variable for the content from the name of the file.

Note that the signature for [`fread()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) is:

```
size_t fread( void *buffer, size_t size, size_t count, FILE *stream );
```

The posted code, if `wspfile` was an array, would be asking `fread()` to read `1` item of `7` bytes in size. If this was successful, `fread()` would return `1` as it returns the number of items read, not the number of bytes. The following line:

```
wspfile[rc] = '\0';
```

would effectively truncate the array to a single byte. Change the order of the `size` and `count` arguments to correct this.

Answer (score 0):

```
rc = fread(wspfile,sizeof(wspfile)-1,1, fp);
```

incorrect, since `wspfile` is string-literal. Modifying of this literal is undefined behaviour.
Use other buffer, or may be `std::string`.

n3337 2.14.5/12

> Whether all string literals are distinct (that is, are stored in nonoverlapping objects) is implementation-
> defined. The effect of attempting to modify a string literal is undefined.